# What's the `.idx`, `.nr`, `.tit` and `.ini` files?

Tags: file-extension

I downloaded a software, and in its store data directory observed some files with extensions `.idx`,`.nr`,`.tit` and `.ini`.

[image]

I don't know what those files are for. Can I extract any data from them ?

Comment: Please provide more details as to what software you downloaded, platform on which you are and what you were trying to do ?

Comment: Any program can give files it creates any extensions it wants.  How the data inside the extensioned file is interpreted is implemented by the specific program.  There is no standard format of data for specific extensions.  It's all up to the program that created the file.